# How I can sync the data upon updating and deleting from adjacency list table into closure one?

Tags: sql-server, trigger

In my sqlserver database I am trying to sync my data with a closure table.

So far I made a table:

```
CREATE TABLE mydb.dbo.files (
    id bigint IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    name nvarchar(255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    folder bigint NULL,
    [type] nvarchar(10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS DEFAULT 'FOLDER' NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK__3213E83FDB19A582 PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT folder_fk FOREIGN KEY (folder) REFERENCES mydb.dbo.files(id)
);
ALTER TABLE mydb.dbo.files WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT CK__files__type__403A8C7D CHECK ([type]='FOLDER' OR [type]='FILE');

CREATE TABLE mydb.dbo.files_closure (
    parent_id bigint NOT NULL,
    child_id bigint NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT files_closure_pk PRIMARY KEY (parent_id,child_id),
    CONSTRAINT files_closure_ancestor_fk FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES mydb.dbo.files(id),
    CONSTRAINT files_closure_decedant_fk FOREIGN KEY (child_id) REFERENCES mydb.dbo.files(id)
);
```

In table `files` I set an hierarcical data where each record points to its parent via column `folder`. In other words, I am emulating a file structure in my database.

And I inserted some dummy data:

```
-- Clean existing data in order to reproduce inserion in this question 
DELETE FROM files;

-- For simplicity I reset auto increment
SET IDENTITY_INSERT files ON
DBCC CHECKIDENT('files', RESEED, 0)

INSERT INTO files (id,name,"type") VALUES
(1,'fol1','FOLDER'),
(2,'fol2','FOLDER'),
(3,'fol3','FOLDER');

INSERT INTO files (id,name,"type",folder) VALUES
(4,'fol1.1','FOLDER',2),
(5,'fol1.2','FOLDER',2),
(6,'fol1.3','FOLDER',2);


INSERT INTO files (id,name,"type",folder) VALUES
(7,'MYFUILE.txt','FILE',2),
(8,'MYFILE2.txt','FILE',4),
(9,'Another.jpg','FILE',4),
(10,'Another.jpg','FILE',1);
```

But I am trying once I insert into the list to auto-sync via triggers into a closure table. I initialised the closure like this:

```
DELETE FROM files_closure;

WITH RecursiveCTE AS (

    SELECT
        id AS parent_id,
        id AS child_id
    FROM
        files
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        cte.parent_id,
        f.id AS child_id
    FROM
        RecursiveCTE cte
    JOIN
        files f ON cte.child_id = f.folder
)

INSERT INTO files_closure (parent_id, child_id)
SELECT parent_id, child_id
FROM RecursiveCTE;
```

And I am trying to implement some triggers in order to sync the data between 2 tables. The way I am trying to do is using triggers.

For inserting new records in the `files` table I did:

```
CREATE TRIGGER "insert_sync_closure" ON files
AFTER insert AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO files_closure(parent_id,child_id)
    select files_closure.parent_id as parent_id ,INSERTED.id as child_id
    from INSERTED join files_closure on INSERTED.id=files_closure.parent_id
    where  files_closure.child_id = INSERTED.folder
END
```

But I am stuck upon implementing a trigger that is triggered upon update and delete on `files` table. Can you help me with that? I am trying upon changing the `folder` in `files` table to update any nessesary records in the `files_closure` one.

Furthermore, I want once removing records from `files` to also update the `files_closure` accorditly.

## Edit 1

For updating I tried:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS "update_sync_closure";

CREATE TRIGGER "update_sync_closure" ON files
AFTER update AS
BEGIN

    -- Get the old and new parent_id of the updated row(s)

    DECLARE @old_parent_id bigint, @new_parent_id bigint, @new_id bigint;
    SELECT 
        @old_parent_id = deleted.folder, 
        @new_parent_id = inserted.folder,
        @new_id = inserted.id
    FROM deleted
    JOIN inserted ON deleted.id = inserted.id;

       
    DELETE FROM files_closure
    WHERE child_id IN (
      SELECT child_id
      FROM files_closure
      WHERE child_id = @old_parent_id
    )
    AND parent_id IN (
      SELECT parent_id
      FROM files_closure
      WHERE parent_id = @old_parent_id
      AND child_id != parent_id
    );
       
    -- Insert the new row(s) into the files_closure table

    INSERT INTO files_closure
    SELECT a.child_id, b.parent_id
    FROM files_closure a
    CROSS JOIN files_closure b
    WHERE a.child_id = @new_id
    AND b.parent_id = @new_parent_id;
END;
```

But once I try to update:

```
UPDATE files set folder = 2 where id = 4;
```

I get the error:

```
SQL Error [2627] [23000]: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'files_closure_pk'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.files_closure'. The duplicate key value is (4, 2).
```

How I can update or remove duplicate lines?

Comment: "*But I am stuck upon implementing a trigger that is triggered upon update and delete on `files` table.*" - What do you want that trigger to do? What are you actually stuck on with doing that?

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: Note that this an "adjacency list" model, not a "nested set" model.

Comment: The insert statement in your attempted update trigger doesn't specify the target columns explicitly and simply goes `INSERT INTO files_closure SELECT ...`.  That means that the values provided by the select are inserted into the columns according to the table definition, i.e. the first value of the tuple will go into `parent_id` and the second one into `child_id`.  However, the select itself returns child IDs first, then parent IDs.  Don't know if that is *the* issue but it's *an* issue at least.  Either swap the columns in the select or, better still, specify the target columns explicitly.